# How to connect socket.io clients using a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a number of socket.io servers serving on iterative ports (port 4001, 4002, 4003, etc)

I want to connect each socket client to the corresponding servers using a loop:

```
connectSockets = (sensors) => {
  const responses = {};

  for (const [idx, sensor] of sensors.entries()) {
    const socket = socketIOClient(`${endpointBase}:${port + idx}`);

    socket.on(`From::${sensor}`, data => {
      responses[sensor] = data
    });
  }

  this.setState({
    responses
  });
};
```

When I break inside the loop on:

```
responses[sensor] = data
```

I can see the data. It is even getting assigned to the appropriate "responses" property.

However, when I get out of the loop and break in setState I see:

```
responses = {}
```

No idea why. Scoping issue of some kind? Or maybe I am confused as to how socket.io works - first time using it. Interestingly when I break on "const socket" i get three iterations as I expect, but when I break on "responses[sensor] = data" I get a lot more than 3 iterations. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured it out on my own. As it turns out it was a mis-understanding as to how socket.io works. As t.niese mentions the callback is async.

What i needed to do was set the state within the socket connection since "data" will not necessarily be available when the loop completes:

```
  socket.on(`From::${sensor}`, data => {
    responses[sensor] = data
    this.setState({responses});
  });
```

Worked perfectly.

Comment: It is not a scoping issue. The callback passed to `socket.on(` is called async, so it is called after the loop finished. So if you call `this.setState` after the loop, then the assignment of `data` to response did not yet happen, and if you break at that point with the debugger the `responses` is still `{}`.

Comment: @t.niese I thought that might be it as well, but the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback) didn't mention it. Make sense though thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not as you assumed in your question (or your answer) as scoping issue, but related to when certain pats of the code are execute. If you place some `console.log` (or breakpoints in your code) it will become obvious:

```
connectSockets = (sensors) => {
  const responses = {};

  console.log('before loop')
  for (const [idx, sensor] of sensors.entries()) {
    const socket = socketIOClient(`${endpointBase}:${port + idx}`);

    socket.on(`From::${sensor}`, data => {
      console.log(`socket.on callback for: ${sensor}`)
      responses[sensor] = data
    });
  }
  console.log('after loop')

  this.setState({responses});
};
```

The output of in the console, or the order in which those breakpoints are reach is:

```
before loop
after loop
socket.on callback for: ...
...
socket.on callback for: ...
```

The event handlers registered with `.on` are called at the time when an even happens, but because JavaScript is not multi threaded, the event handling cannot happen at the same time when you register an event handler with `.on`.

You can solve that - as you already figured out - by moving the `this.setState({responses})` to the event callback.Now you call `this.setState`  multiple times. If this is a problem, depends on your `setState` function.

Answer (score 0):

`responses[sensor] = data` is triggered asynchronously at a later pointer in time.
`this.setState({responses})` is being called in the same event loop. This is the reason you wouldn't find it populated with anything.